# How to remove not used classes from JQuery UI

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

We are using JQuery UI lib for some interface enhancements which works great. But since we don't need to support IE6 and other old browsers, there is no need for classes like:

> `.ui-corner-all, .ui-corner-top, .ui-corner-left, .ui-corner-tl`

which are added by JQuery UI. Is there any way to tell JQuery UI not to add them? It is no problem to remove style from it, but it doesn't look good when you have there a lot of empty classes.

Comment: There is no option in the library to tell which classes to add or not. Btw, they are not there to *support IE6*, they are there to style the widgets with `border-radius` ([doc](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/API)) - and they are no harm, apart from you, nobody go check your html source code ;-)

Comment: yes, I know, but it is not necessary for some widgets. I went through documentation and didn't find any options. Just asking to make sure I didn't overlook anything

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one possible way to achieve this.

The jquery ui widgets raises a 'create' event that is triggered between the execution of the _create() and _init() methods:

```
this._create();
this._trigger( "create" );
this._init();
```

This event is raised from the base object Widget so it is available to all the widgets implementing it.

The classes for 'ui-corner-xxx' (and others) are typically created in the '_create()' method, so you could bind an event handler to the 'create' option of the widgets to remove those classes. Something like:

```
var classesToRemove = ['ui-corner-all', 'ui-corner-top',
    'ui-corner-bottom', 'ui-corner-right', 'ui-corner-left',
    'ui-corner-tl', 'ui-corner-tr', 'ui-corner-bl', 'ui-corner-br'];

var removeClassesCreateHandler = function(event, ui) {
    var that = this;
    $.each(classesToRemove, function(idx, val) {
        $('.' + val, that).removeClass(val);
    });
};

$("#accordion").accordion({
    create: removeClassesCreateHandler
});
```

Here is a working example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/M8Kcv/).

---

**About the `create` event of jQuery UI Widgets**

It is important to note that not all jQuery ui widgets actually implements the Widget Factory (thanks to the solution above is possible).

So, even though the documentation page shows a `create` option, it is not necessarily available.

This the case for the Datepicker for instance. It still relies on pretty old code and does not implement the Widget factory (yet - it is planned to be refactored).

Answer (score 0):

I used [Dust-Me selectors](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/) to remove unnecessary css. It really helped me a lot to get rid of unused styles.

Comment: This is for finding unused css selectors in css files, not to remove them from html...

Comment: @DidierG.: Oops. I think I should again through question.